# Pink Screen in Unity Game (Overcooked)

Tags: unity, games, crash

I was trying to play a game called "Overcooked" which seems to use **Unity and Directx10?** or something so so.

Well, as soon as I execute the game, it normally opens up with the unity logo animation, and then goes to a pink screen

So I ran it through the terminal, and it gave me this.

```
1. wine Overcooked.exe fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
stub fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub! Mono path[0] = (*###pathtomono*)
    fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f414,0x00000000), stub! fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW
(L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x33f414,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33f414,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x10058, 0x140a70): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f5c4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_check_feature_level_support Ignoring adapter type.
fixme:winediag:dxgi_check_feature_level_support None of the
requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the
current shader backend. 
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW
((null),0,0x33f5d4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_check_feature_level_support Ignoring adapter type.
fixme:winediag:dxgi_check_feature_level_support None of the
requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the
current shader backend. fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW
((null),0,0x33f744,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM
stub! fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d
0x145588, adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL,
src_format WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, dst_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM
stub! fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d
0x145588, adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL,
src_format WINED3DFMT_B10G10R10A2_UNORM, dst_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B5G5R5A1_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM
stub! fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d
0x145588, adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL,
src_format WINED3DFMT_B5G5R5X1_UNORM, dst_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B10G10R10A2_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM
stub! fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d
0x145588, adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL,
src_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM, dst_format
WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B5G5R5A1_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_check_device_format_conversion wined3d 0x145588,
adapter_idx 0, device_type WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, src_format
WINED3DFMT_B5G5R5X1_UNORM, dst_format WINED3DFMT_B5G6R5_UNORM stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f0c4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled D3DFORMAT
0xffffffff fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled
D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat
Unhandled D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff
fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled D3DFORMAT
0xffffffff fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled
D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized
0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized
(0x36314644) in the format lookup table
fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",0x687e978): stub
fixme:win:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x100 for device
0. fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x10058, filter=0x33fc2c,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification
handle! fixme:win:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x100 for
device 0. fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification
(handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB! fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW
(hwnd=0x10058, filter=0x33fb50,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake
device notification handle! fixme:win:RegisterRawInputDevices
Unhandled flags 0x100 for device 0.
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x10058,
filter=0x33fc24,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification
handle! fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0x10058 00000000): stub
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0xf2c107a0, 0x15e39aa8,
10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0xf2c107a0
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum unsupported flags
0x00000030 fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum
unsupported flags 0x00000030
fixme:d3d_shader:shader_glsl_declare_generic_vertex_attribute
Unhandled sysval semantic 0x1.
^Cfixme:console:CONSOLE_DefaultHandler Terminating process 8 on
event 0
```

These are my computer specs

```
Ubuntu 16 64-bit running Wine-1.9.16
Memory : 7.7 GB
Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 
GPU : Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
HD space : 480 gb left
```

Thanks a lot, please help me :s